# It's my birthday

Tags: number-sequence

Just like last year, my age is a number you can score with one dart. The year before that, it wasn't, and it won't be next year.

How old am I?

Comment: I tend to read puzzles I see on the HNQ. This one made me smile *because I could actually SOLVE it* and because we are the same age. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are...

> **51.** Since you can score it (triple 17) and a 50 (bullseye) on a dartboard with a single dart, but not a 49 or a 52.

Comment: ...And happy birthday! :) Hope the party you *threw* was a real *hit*! [Sorry.]

Answer (score 3):

Last and next year, your age couldn't be thrown with a single dart, but this year you can, right? You are...

> ...either 30, 36, 42, 45, 48, 54, 57 or 60 years old!

Misread the question a little, you are now

> 51, congrats!